# Does PingFederate and ADFS support ECP (Enhanced Client and Proxy) Profile?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.0, pingfederate

Does PingFederate and ADFS support SAML ECP (Enhanced Client and Proxy) Profile? If yes, is there any documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, PF supports ECP as I believe it is required per SAML 2.0 compliance testing. I would contact them directly for more info as it has very little documentation around it.

Comment: ECP support in PingFederate is limited to the SAML 2.0 compliance testbed. Supporting products outside of that testbed would be a Client Services engagement.

Answer (score 1):

No idea about Ping but for ADFS, no it doesn't support ECP.